# how to finish a listActivity on pressing the back button on device

Tags: android, button, listactivity, back, activity-finish

i m using the following code to finish an activity but i want to finish the list activity on back press event . help me
Thanks in advance

```
public void onBackPressed() {
         AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
            alertDialog.setMessage("Want to exit ?");  
            alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                  for(Activity activity:activities)
                       activity.finish();
            } });   
            alertDialog.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  

            }});   
          alertDialog.show();  
    }
```

Comment: for(Activity activity:activities)
                       activity.finish();  -- are you maintaining a list of activities across your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not modifying the your code,just i am suggesting new code here,

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ProgressController.this).setTitle(
        "Attention").setMessage(
        "Want to exit ?")
        .setPositiveButton("YES",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("NO",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {

                    }
                }).show();
        return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

        //return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  Code should be modified like below..

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
         alertDialog.setMessage("Want to exit ?");  
         alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
              finish();
         } });   
         alertDialog.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  

               return;
         }});   
       alertDialog.show(); 

    }
```

Comment: your suggesation is helpful but it is same as my code was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Add a cancel listener to your alert dialog, and close your activity from within there.

```
    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
    alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```